# CMake Error: install EXPORT includes target which requires target that is not in any export set

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm writing a library that has a few dependencies that are pulled in via CMake's FetchContent. In my toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`, close to the top I have:

`include(external/dependencies.cmake)` which contains

```
include(FetchContent)
   
# a pretty awesome text formatting library
option(_USE_FMT "include components for formatting helpers based on fmt" ON)
if(_USE_FMT)
FetchContent_Declare(
  fmt_fc
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
  GIT_TAG 7.1.3
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt_fc)
endif()
       
FetchContent_Declare(
  eigen_fc
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror.git
  GIT_TAG 3.3.7
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
)

# # do the actual fetching

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(eigen_fc)
```

so I have a couple of dependencies, fmt and eigen, with fmt being optional. Later on in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` I have a

```
add_library(my_common "")
add_library(my::my_common ALIAS my_common)
#...
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(extras)
```

in `src`, I have several `target_sources()` statements that add files to the target and in one directory I have a

```
target_link_libraries(my_common
  PUBLIC
    eigen 
)
```

and in `extras` I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that follows the same pattern (not shown is a guard to omit adding this directory if the option `_USE_FMT` is set as such):

```
target_sources(my_common
PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/geometry_adapters.hpp>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${MY_COMMON_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}/geometry_adapters.hpp>
)
# ...
target_link_libraries(my_common
PUBLIC
  fmt::fmt
)
```

later in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` I have

```
install(TARGETS my_common EXPORT my_common-targets
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/my_common
)
```

prior to me adding `fmt` with just `eigen` (and actually `catch2` as well, although it's snipped out for brevity) everything was great this worked as I would've expected it to. However after adding fmt, I'm getting this error in the generation phase:

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "my_common-targets" ...) includes target "my_common" which requires target "fmt" that is not in any export set.
```

adding `fmt` to the install command above fixes it, but that doesn't seem right--why is this required for fmt and not eigen (or catch2)? All three of those libraries have very good cmake support and have their own `install (TARGETS ... EXPORT)` command. One thing I can think of might be that eigen and catch2 are header only?

Any thoughts?

Comment: According to fmt project [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), it automatically performs installation only when it is a **top-level** project. For perform installation in case it is subproject, you need to set `FMT_INSTALL` option. E.g. in your `CMakeLists.txt` you could add the line `option(FMT_INSTALL "Enable install for fmt project" ON)` before `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt_fc)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in fmt, install rules are disabled if it's a subproject...

```
# Determine if fmt is built as a subproject (using add_subdirectory)
# or if it is the master project.
if (NOT DEFINED FMT_MASTER_PROJECT)
  set(FMT_MASTER_PROJECT OFF)
  if (CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)
    set(FMT_MASTER_PROJECT ON)
    message(STATUS "CMake version: ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
  endif ()
endif ()
```

ref: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/373262f9fbacab7d868ab10f1f0b20978c096572/CMakeLists.txt#L8-L16

```
option(FMT_INSTALL "Generate the install target." ${FMT_MASTER_PROJECT})
```

ref: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/373262f9fbacab7d868ab10f1f0b20978c096572/CMakeLists.txt#L67

then:

```
# Install targets.
if (FMT_INSTALL)
  ...
```

https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/373262f9fbacab7d868ab10f1f0b20978c096572/CMakeLists.txt#L260-L261

If [CMP0077](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0077.html) is set to new, you can try to use `set(FMT_INSTALL ON)`

Comment: hot dang...thanks.  Seems weird to have that option, but I guess it's to allow for header only use

Comment: this is mostly use when you have a super build project which use fmt internally (using add_subdirectory or FetchContent), thus you don't want to pollute your super project install target with the fmt one (especially if fmt is internal and static linked)